# Для того(,) чтобы улыбнуться... а для того(,) чтобы нахмуриться(,) —

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, запятая-перед-тире, составные-союзы

Нужны запятые? Применяется ли правило о том, что, если составной союз является частью однородного ряда, запятая ставится перед второй частью? Если нет, то почему?

`Для того(,) чтобы улыбнуться, нужно задействовать 17 мышц, а для того(,) чтобы нахмуриться(,) — 43.`

Comment: "Перед первым союзом паузы нет, а перед вторым есть".  Почему это? Прочитать можно как угодно. Для меня одинаково звучит – с паузами после "улыбнуться" и "нахмуриться". И союз здесь – "для того чтобы".

Comment: Максим, вы часто игнорируете комментарии... Поделитесь хотя бы,  что за "правило о том, что, если составной союз является частью однородного ряда, запятая ставится перед второй частью". И еще. Сначала вы пишете о **составном** союзе, а потом: "Перед первым союзом паузы нет, а перед вторым есть". Может, тогда надо написать: "Перед **второй частью** составного союза"?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец А может, занят, а не игнорирую? Позже вам дам то, что вы хотите. Ещë вопрос задам, а через время выполню ваши требования к вопросу.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо!

Comment: Позже дам ссылку.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Держите ссылку: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138 Там пункт 3-4. Извиняюсь, конечно, что так поздно, но лучше поздно, чем никогда.